# Did the Panel class move to another library in bokeh for new version of Bokeh

Tags: python, tabs, bokeh, panel

I have a bokeh application using Tabs and Panel widgets.  I used to do:
`from bokeh.models import Tabs,Panel`

I recently did a new installation of python 3.8 and subsequently bokeh (3.0.2) and now  `Panel` cannot be imported from  `bokeh.models`.  Online examples cite importing from `bokeh.models.widgets` but that does not work either.   The error message I get is `cannot import name 'Panel' from 'bokeh.models.widgets' (C:\Users\_my_username_\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\bokeh\models\widgets\__init__.py)`

Comment: Bokeh 3.0 was a new major release with breaking changes, see the  migration guides for details like these: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/wiki/Migration-Guides#300

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `Panel` has been renamed `TabPanel` in Bokeh 3.0.3.

[The docs for version 2.4.3](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/2.4.3/docs/reference/models/layouts.html?highlight=panel#bokeh.models.Panel) say this:

> ## Panel
>
> `class Panel(*args, **kwargs)`
>
> Bases: [`Model`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/2.4.3/docs/reference/model.html#bokeh.model.Model)
>
> A single-widget container with title bar and controls.

And [the docs for version 3.0.3](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/3.0.3/docs/reference/models/layouts.html#bokeh.models.TabPanel) say this:

> `class TabPanel(*args: Any, id: ID | None = None, **kwargs: Any)`
>
> Bases: [`Model`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/3.0.3/docs/reference/model.html#bokeh.model.Model)
>
> A single-widget container with title bar and controls.

Based on that information, I think they're referring to the same thing and `from bokeh.models import TabPanel` would work.